# Access Alpine.js x-data function from within an event

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Currently I am trying to modify a common variable between two blocks of data in Alpine.js, but trying to keep both blocks as independent as possible. One block will be executed after the first one is finished. The way I am doing this is by adding an event to inform the second block it is ready for processing, and I hide both blocks according to a variable.

```
<div x-show="!$store.isSecondBlock" x-data="myFirstData()">
</div>
<div id="secondBlock" x-show="!$store.isSecondBlock" x-data="mySecondData()">
</div>
```

Where `myFirstData()` and `mySecondData()` are defined in another file as:

```
window.myFirstData = function(){
    return {
        next(){
            //Modifies this.$store.sharedData
            document.getElementById("secondBlock").dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('secondBlockReady'));
            this.$store.isSecondBlock = true;
        },
    }
}

window.mySecondData = function(){
    return {
        next2(){
            //Some stuff here
        },
        init(){
            document.getElementById("secondBlock").addEventListener('secondBlockReady', function(e){
                this.next2();
            });
        },
    }
}
```

And the store is created as:

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('isSecondBlock', False);
    Alpine.store('sharedData', [an array here]);
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to execute the function `next2()` in the event listener `Uncaught TypeError: this.next2 is not a function at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>`. I check and I can't even access `this.$store.sharedData` variable from there.

So I get to the point where the event listener is executed when the `next()` function in `myFirstData()` is executed , but the `next2()` is never called because can't be accessed.

**It is important that `next2()` function of `mySecondData` is run after `next()` is run in `myFirstData`.** And also important to make sure the `mySecondData` can run with other blocks of data that don't need to be `myFirstData`, and only be triggered when the event is executed. One way to imagine it is as a pipeline where each step modifies a shared object and the next step is only executed when the first one finishes.

Is there any approach I can take to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab a reference to the `mySecondData` function within the `init` and use that reference inside the Event Listener so that the Listener function knows how to reference `next2()`

```
    window.mySecondData = function(){
    return {
        next2(){
            alert('hi');
        },
        init(){
            self = this;
            document.getElementById("secondBlock").addEventListener('secondBlockReady', function(e){
                self.next2();
            });
        },
    }
```

also, the `false` should not be capitalized, but I'm sure in your code it is already not capitalized.

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('isSecondBlock', false);
    Alpine.store('sharedData', ["an", "array", "here"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was during the simplification I incorrectly typed `F`. Thanks, gonna try later. Is there anywhere I can read about the reason behind this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this  ... "this" inside of the function(e) assigned to the secondBlockReady Event Listener has a different scope than the "this" in the parent mySecondData function .. BTW, name that variable anything you want, does not have to be names self ...